# LOAD DATA INFILE is skipping first column

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, phpquery

The following is skipping the first column in the table

```
$load ="LOAD DATA INFILE '$inputFile' INTO TABLE $tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

The infile has proper data in proper columns

What's wrong ?

Comment: You specified IGNORE 1 LINES. What is the question?

Comment: IGNORE 1 Lines is to exclude the headers. That's working fine. But data is not aligning to the columns... it starts adding data from second column....

Comment: Please provide some lines from the CSV file to reproduce the problem, also CREATE TABLE statement.